# USB host to host connector with PIC18F2550

Tags: pic

I'm working on project to design a usb cable between two PCs with PIC182550 as controller.How can I connect
both the PCs since there is one USB interface in the PIC?

Comment: What functionality do you have in mind? A chip with one USB slave peripheral can be the slave of only one computer at a time. No cable design can change this.

Comment: I was thinking of using the USB interface and the RS232 on the other PC. Can you please suggest others way(s) to accomplish this project if this technique is not practical.

Comment: Just use 2 PICs; one for each PC's USB. And the PICs can talk with each other through SPI.

Comment: @Jahoh: be more precise. Do you want the two PCs to communicate via virtual serial ports? Or use USB on one PC and an existing serial port on the other?

Comment: I am targetting the USB on both the PCs so as to make use of 480Mbps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not if you want to connect this device to both PCs via USB.  You could use two PICs and have them communicate to each other on-board via high speed UART connection or something.  With the two PICs running at the same instruction frequency and close to each other on the same board, you can use a fast non-standard baud rate to get pretty good data rate using their UARTs.  Of course you can implement your on scheme with other lines tied together perhaps using the parallel ports with some handshaking lines.

In any case, the point is that each PIC can only function as a single host on a single USB.  You will need one of them for each USB connection.

### Added:

I just noticed you mentioned 480 Mb/s in comments.  Seriously!!?  Even the briefest skim of the datasheet would have revealed this PIC can only support 12 Mb/s.  This is clearly pointed out in the second bullet of the features highlights on page 1.  Even without this, stop and *think* about it just a little.  480 Mb/s is 60 Mbyte/s.  How do you imagine at PIC with a maximum oscillator speed of 48 MHz (again on page 1 in the highlights), which results in a maximum instruction rate of 12 MHz is supposed to handle 60 Mbyte/s?  That would be 5 bytes *per instruction cycle*.

Comment: Which option is best between SPI and UART for connecting two PCs in as far as speed is concerned.

Comment: Ethernet. (There are cables you can buy with a device in them that plug into two PCs and pretend to be a very small network). Of the other two options, SPI can go faster, but still nowhere near 480Mb/sec. 1Mb/sec is more reasonable to aim for.

Comment: If the PCs have parallel ports, there's always the good old http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LapLink_cable Laplink cable. These days Laplink make USB-ethernet-USB cables as I described above.

Comment: When using SPI is it practical to use one crystal oscillator for both the mircocontrollers (PIC18F2550)?