# Microcontroller with two USB interfaces and high speed (480Mbps)

Tags: microcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [USB host to host connector with PIC18F2550](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/47118/usb-host-to-host-connector-with-pic18f2550)

I'm working on my final year project and designing a host-to-host (PC-to-PC) USB connector with a microcontroller in between. Is there any microcontroller that can operate at high speed (480Mbps) and also have two USB interfaces? If there is non, what other technologies or functionality are practical to designing such a connector.

Comment: It would really be helpful if you could explain what your overall goal is. If it's just data communication between the two USB hosts, what is the role of the microcontroller? Why not just connect two FTDI chips back-to-back? Why not use Ethernet?

Comment: How about two simple USB enabled microcontrollers back to back?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rehash of [USB host to host connector with PIC18F2550](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/47118/usb-host-to-host-connector-with-pic18f2550) isn't it?

http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/arm/sam3u.aspx is an example of an ARM device with high-speed USB. Note that it only has one uplink port; I don't expect you'll be able to find a device with two uplinks. It will also be quite difficult to transmit data to another one at that speed.

I strongly reccomend that you downgrade your expectations to 12Mbps, at which point it gets a lot easier. Have you decided what sort of USB device you want to present to the host PCs? Are you prepared to write your own drivers or are you going to emulate something?

Answer (score 1):

A two-core XMOS device could implement two high-speed USB interfaces:

http://www.xmos.com/